# invisbile submit button on form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, show

I have a form constrained by validation code.
ex. userName has to have alphabet characters.
And hence returns true or false.

```
function isAlphapet()
{
  var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  var namee=document.validation.userName.value;
  var nalt=document.getElementById('name1');
  if(namee!="")
   {
      if(!namee.match(alphaExp))
      {
       nalt.innerHTML="<font color='red'> Invalid Name: " + document.validation.userName.value + "</font>";
       document.validation.userName.focus();
       document.validation.userName.value="";
       //This will remove the success class if the user tries to modify it incorrectly.
       document.getElementById("userName").className = document.getElementById("userName").className.replace(" validationSuccess", "");
       //This is calling the css class name validationError to color the text box border in red if there is an error.
       //Leaving the replacing attribute empty incase the user hasn't input the correct string.
       document.getElementById("userName").className = document.getElementById("userName").className + " validationError";
         return false;  
       }else{//if it's validated correctly
          nalt.innerHTML="";
         //The text box should be green.
          document.getElementById("userName").className = document.getElementById("userName").className + " validationSuccess";
            return true; 
        }
   }
  else  if(namee.length==0) { //if the user leaves it blank.
   nalt.innerHTML="<font color='red'> Enter Name</font>";
    document.getElementById('name1').focus();
    document.getElementById("userName").className = document.getElementById("userName").className.replace(" validationSuccess", "");
    document.getElementById("userName").className = document.getElementById("userName").className + " validationError";
    //The above is explained on line 27+.
   return false;
    }
}
```

and in the form for the userName text box I have:

```
Your Name:<br /><input name="userName" id="userName" onBlur="isAlphapet()" type="text" size="20" maxlength="25" /><br />
```

I need my button to be enabled once the above returns true. But for some reason isAlphapet is not returning anything when I try to use it in JScript within the body.

Does anyone have a solution?

Much appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Thank you for responding Srini.

Hmm. No the entire validation function stopped working after I made the changes. What i'm trying to achieve is a little simpler than what it sounds like. I need an if statement or something like the following:

```
if (isAlphapet()== true && emailvalid()== true && browserValid()==true){
    document.validation.sumb.disabled=false;
}
else{
    document.validation.subm.diabled=true;
}
```

Where validation is the name of my form. I've tried to use this in the header and in the body. It doesn't recognize the return value of my functions in either. But the button disable and enable works ONLY after the /form tag

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
              <html>
            <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function isAlphapet()
            {

             var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
             var namee=document.getElementById('userName').value;

             var nalt=document.getElementById('name1');
      if(namee!="")
      {
    if(!namee.match(alphaExp))
    {
        alert(namee);       


        nalt.innerHTML="<span style='color:red;'> Invalid Name: " + namee + "</span>";
        document.validation.userName.focus();
        document.validation.userName.value="";
   //This will remove the success class if the user tries to modify it incorrectly.
         document.getElementById("userName").className = document.getElementById("userName").className.replace("             validationSuccess",        "");
   //This is calling the css class name validationError to color the text box border in red if there is an error.
   //Leaving the replacing attribute empty incase the user hasn't input the correct string.
         document.getElementById("userName").className = document.getElementById("userName").className + " validationError";
         return false;  
      }

      else{//if it's validated correctly
      nalt.innerHTML="";
     //The text box should be green.
      document.getElementById("userName").className = document.getElementById("userName").className + " validationSuccess";
        return true; 
      }
  }
    else  if(namee.length==0) { //if the user leaves it blank.
       nalt.innerHTML="<font color='red'> Enter Name</font>";
       document.getElementById('name1').focus();
       document.getElementById("userName").className = document.getElementById("userName").className.replace(" validationSuccess", "");
       document.getElementById("userName").className = document.getElementById("userName").className + " validationError";
//The above is explained on line 27+.
      return false;
    }
 }

            </script>
            </head>
        <body>
         <div style="float:left">
            <form>
                Your Name:<br /><input name="userName" id="userName" onBlur="isAlphapet()" type="text" size="20" maxlength=                    "25" /><br />
            </form>
        </div>
          <div id="name1" style="float:left"></div>
         </body>
        </html>
```